# Converting a SequenceCharSequence array into a smaller array of the same type that excludes indices that have - chars

Tags: java, arrays, string, dna-sequence

the following method ends up building strings that start with null characters and I dont know why. Any explanation and or better solution would be greatly appreciated.
Sincerely,
mrBurlCe

```
/* sample input:
SequenceCharSequence[] seqs = new SequenceCharSequence[3][7]; 

seqs[0] = {'A', 'T', 'A', '-', 'G', 'T', 'C'};

seqs[1] = {'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', '-', 'T', 'G'};

seqs[2] = {'A', 'C', '-', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'A'};

int[] range = {1, 7};

expected output variable equivalence:

ugsS[0] == "TTC";

ugsS[1] == "TTG";

ugsS[3] == "CTA";
*/
/* the method below is supposed to take in a SequenceCharSequence[x][y] array of standard      
IUPAC nucleic acid characters such as A, T, G, C and -.
it looks at all indices of y inside and including the given range for '-' chars across 
outer indices(x).
if all elements of the current index are not '-' chars the are added to their   
corresponding
outer index ,x, in the String[] ugsS[x]
*/ 
static String[] gsStr(SequenceCharSequence[] seqs, int[] range) {
    String[] ugsS = new String[seqs.length];
    for(int i = range[0]; i < range[1]; i++) {
        boolean notGap = true;
        for(int sI = 0; sI < seqs.length; sI++) {
            if(seqs[sI].charAt(i) == '-') {
                notGap = false;
            } 
        }
        if(notGap) {
            for(int sII = 0; sII < seqs.length; sII++) {
                ugsS[sII] += seqs[sII].charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return ugsS;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample some input and the expected output?

Comment: Have you stepped through and inspected `seqs[sII].charAt(i)`?

Comment: sure and sorry about that

Comment: You're not initializing the strings in your array; `String[] ugsS = new String[seqs.length];` results in an array of nulls.  `+=` implicitly casts the nulls to strings.

Comment: to adamdc78, would Arrays.fill(ugsS, "") work?

Comment: adamdc78 you were correct, how do I accept your answer?

Comment: How big are your sequences?  If they're even a few hundred characters each, you could get performance improvements by using StringBuilders instead of Strings.  I'll write up an answer shortly and you can accept that.

Comment: the character lengths vary depending on what the end user wants to evaluate, sequence ranges from a small length, like 70 chars, to larger lengths, like tens of thousands of chars, so it really depends. Any improved efficiency that maintains versatility is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] ugsS = new String[seqs.length];
```

This only allocates the space for your strings; you'll need to initialize your array.

```
StringBuilder[] ugsS = new String[seqs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < seqs.length; ++i)
  ugsS[i] = new StringBuilder(seqs[i].length());
```

This will initialize an array of StringBuilders, each of which has an initial length of the associated sequence.

```
if(notGap) {
  for(int sII = 0; sII < seqs.length; sII++) {
     ugsS[sII].append(seqs[sII].charAt(i));
  }
}
```

This replaces your += and avoids placing another String on the heap to be garbage collected later on.

When you want to display or otherwise access your compacted sequences, use the `.toString()` method on the string builder instance.